# Spout throttling in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I understand that `max.spout.pending` is a simple way to achieve back-pressure with `acking-enabled`.
I want to understand, do we still need `max.spout.pending` to throttle the spout now that the back-pressure has been implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you point to the page that mentions this implementation of automatic back-pressure?

Comment: Not necessary, just enable this configuration **topology.backpressure.enable: true**

Answer (score 0):

From `Storm 1.0.0` onwards, backpressure automation is provided and is configurable by high/low watermarks (`disruptor.highwatermark/disruptor.lowwatermark`) for bolt's receiver buffer and bolt's buffer size (`executor.'receive/send'.buffer.size`).
So the spout throttles/release the tuples to bolts on the basis of the watermarks.

For more info, see: http://storm.apache.org/2016/04/12/storm100-released.html